# OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 's'

Tags: pandas

I want to convert the unit's timestamp to the current time. When I enter the code below：

```
ad_operation['Change_time'] = pd.to_datetime(ad_operation['Change_time'],unit='s')
```

It has such an error：“OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 's'”

But I copied a data in my file and made it x, it has no problem, I am confused, my data type is int64，Data column has no null value.

```
x = 1529958950
pd.to_datetime(x, unit = 's')

output:Timestamp('2018-06-25 20:35:50')
```

How is this going？

---

Sample Data `ad_operation`:

```
    ad_id     Change_time  Operation_type  Modify_field
0  593323               0               2             2
1  593323               0               2             3
2  593323               0               2             4
3  593323  20190217000000               1             1
4  593323  20190218233855               1             2
5  593323  20190218000000               1             1
6  593323  20190230000000               1             1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dates aren't the number of seconds since the POSIX origin, they are in the format: `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.

```
pd.to_datetime(ad_operation.Change_time, format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S', errors='coerce')
#0                        NaT
#1                        NaT
#2                        NaT
#3        2019-02-17 00:00:00
#4        2019-02-18 23:38:55
#5        2019-02-18 00:00:00
#6                        NaT
#....
```

---

The NAT comes from the rows which are `0`. (or a weird date like February 30th). We can see that the timestamps aren't anything like the one you attempted to use in your troubleshooting:

```
ad_operation[ad_operation.Change_time.ne(0)].Change_time.agg([min, max])
#min    20190216000000
#max    20190319235959
#Name: Change_time, dtype: int64
```