# OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:34

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in a csv file that says `start time`. And the values are like this :

```
0:10:52
4:33:34
1:41:06
21:19:40
0:30:55
22:27:23
```

I wrote the following piece of code to change the datatype of this column to "time" :

```
log_file['start time'] = pd.to_datetime(log_file['start time']).dt.time
```

When I run this piece of code, it gives me the following error :

> OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:34

Can someone please help me understand this error and how to troubleshoot it. I went through the other outofboundsdatetime posts but I couldn't really understand the logic.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55983965/outofboundsdatetime-cannot-convert-input-with-unit-s

Comment: @Jens thanks Jens! I added the format option - log_file['start time'] = pd.to_datetime(log_file['start time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time..... It works fine for all files but one exceptional case... In one of the CSV, the start time is just "5:48".. No seconds are mentioned. It gave : ValueError: time data '5:48' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match).... So I added error = 'ignore' - log_file['start time'] = pd.to_datetime(log_file['start time'],errors='ignore', format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time .... But now it gives this error - AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: I want to add 00 seconds to such exceptional cases. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that some time values are not zero padding, you can pad column value with `Series.str.zfill`

```py
log_file['end time'] = (pd.to_datetime(
    (log_file['start time']
     .str.split(':', expand=True)
     .apply(lambda col: col.str.zfill(2))
     .fillna('00')
     .agg(':'.join, axis=1))
).dt.time)
```

```
print(log_file)

  start time  end time
0    0:10:52  00:10:52
1    4:33:34  04:33:34
2    1:41:06  01:41:06
3   21:19:40  21:19:40
4    0:30:55  00:30:55
5   22:27:23  22:27:23
6     0:0:34  00:00:34
7      0::34  00:00:34
8        ::4  00:00:04
9         :4  00:04:00
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives an error: TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, NoneType found